# Navigation Bar has unnecessary spaces on the left and right sides

Tags: html, css

I've included all the CSS and HTML needed to reproduce my issue. This is my first website and I'm creating a D&D character randomizer. The code I used for my navigation bar is from my teacher. I've looked at other posts on this forum but couldn't seem to fix my issue. Thanks

[Picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqjDo.jpg)

```css
/* CSS for the Menu */
#Menu {
    font-size: 25px; /* Font size of 25 px */
   }
   
   /* CSS for the Menu background */
   #Menu ul {
     list-style-type: none; /* No Bullets */
     overflow: hidden; /* No Scroll Wheel */
     background-color: rgb(77, 39, 21); /* Background colour of the Menu */
     margin-bottom: 0px; /* Margin from the top div is 0 */
     margin-top: 0px /* Margin from the top div is 0 */
   }
   
   /* CSS for Menu Edges*/
   #Menu li {
     float: left; /* Menu is floated to the Left to make it all in one line */
     border-right: 1px solid rgb(104, 99, 99); /* Left border line of 1 px separating blocks. */
     border-left: 1px solid rgb(104, 99, 99); /* Right border line of 1 px separating blocks. */
   
   }
   
   /* CSS for Menu Tabs */
   #Menu li a {
     display: block; /* Turns it into a block display */
     color: rgb(187, 180, 180); /* Background colour of Text */
     text-align: center; /* Aligns text to the middle of the block */ 
     padding: 16px 177px; /* Padding of 16px and 177 px between blocks */
     text-decoration: none; /* Makes sure there are no underlines */
   }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "StylesheetQ.css">

<div id="Menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a class="active" href="Main Page.html">Home</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="About.html">About</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</li></a></li>
       <li><a href="Testimonials.html">Testimonials</li></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Reset the padding to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a padding on your ul.

So write `padding:0;` and you are good to go.

For your projects, you might be interested in using a CSS Reset like [this one](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the left side, but not for the right though

Comment: No it  should work. You still have a space on the right side because you're using `float:left;` with li elements having a specific width. So of course, if the window is wide enough there will be some space left on the right side of your menu bar. Try to resize your browser window and you'll see the space disappear. Now if you want your items to fill the space you might consider a whole different approach. Let go of `float` and use `flex` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Reset you padding to 0.

```
#Menu { 
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 0;
}
```